# How do I get the glass material to stop weirdly showing the object inside the glass?

Tags: materials, glass

[image]

Under the Cycles Render, I inserted a pyramid with the emission material attached to it and it is inside the octagonal shape glass. When I am rendering the scene, the pyramid weirdly is being displayed as seen in the image and this appears to be happening on the edges of the shape. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the glass have any thickness?

Comment: How do I check the glass's material thickness?

Comment: if you didn't design it as a glass cover, like a lantern glass, having just some thickness, then it's a bulk object _full_ of glass material... it will for sure behave different.

Comment: Sorry I am not too sure what you mean. Could you please give me a demonstration as to what I have to do to solve such an issue please?

What I did was that I created a octagonal shape and then I added a glass material to it. What am I supposed to be doing in order to avoid such an issue?

Comment: Read this related post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69616/1853

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that if you set no thickness to the glass then your object becomes a solid piece of glass:

[image]

If you give the glass some thickness (in this example I used a solidify modifier) then it will behave like an object that has glass panes, but is empty inside.

[image]

But the problem is not solved, because the default glass shader has problems dealing with direct light going through it.

Using the tricky glass shader detailed in this post: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles) will give you more realistic results.

[image]